# How to extract a text string using bash (or python on mac)

Tags: python, mysql, bash, nlp

How do you extract the usernames in a text file (example text is in the following) into a mysql database using bash or python on mac?

```
124dave87 10 months ago

:) ...Thank you for making this video.

Reply  ·

kateDVKH 1 year ago
@karluchii19 i'm still trying to figure out who you are?!?

Thanks for replying.
Reply  ·

shotwioke 3 months ago
hey how is everything going with your health-i hope/pray things are going good for you.God bless
Reply  ·   in reply to MrNickkaye (Show the comment)
```

For example, for the above text file, the script will spit out the following:

```
124dave87    
kateDVKH    
shotwioke
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -E "[0-9]+ (month|year|day|week)s? ago" a.txt| grep -Eo "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

I'm sure this can be in one step using awk or sed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the string that starts with the beginning of the line, and ends at the first space character. Is that right?

If so, the fastest/easiest way would probably be:

```
egrep -o "^[^ ]*"
```

*edit* (based on your comment below)

Can you expand a little bit on what exactly you're looking for here? What's the actual purpose? It might help us frame our answers...

That said, if you're just looking to get a list of unique user names, you might try:

```
egrep -o "^[^ ]*" | sort | uniq
```

You could also add a unique constraint to the database table, if your schema allows for it.

Comment: Oh there can be multiple lines per user, so it'd be nice to have a rule of:
- word number "year(s) or month(s) or day(s) or hour(s) ago"
extract the word.

Comment: Edited my response. Still a little unclear as to what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish, though...

Comment: The text file contains comments to a post, and I am trying to extract how many unique users commented to the post. So yes, your answer on sorting by unique usernames helps a lot. I still would like to add more constraints (as described in my first comment) so that it is not picking up every first occurring word as usernames.

Comment: I just edited my example to show you that there can be multiple lines per comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression in Python. For example:

```
import re

test="""124dave87 10 months ago :) ...Thank you for making this video. Reply ·

kateDVKH 1 year ago @karluchii19? i'm still trying to figure out who you are?!? Reply ·

shotwioke 3 months ago hey how is everything going with? your health-i hope/pray things are going good for you.God bless Reply · in reply to MrNickkaye (Show the comment)
"""

for line in test.split('\n'):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', line)
    if(len(words) > 0):
        # write words[0] to mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` is maybe relatively easy to understand:

```
awk '$0 ~ " [0-9]+ (month|year|day|week)s? ago" {print $1}'
```

If the line contains the pattern, print the first word. Pipe to `sort | uniq` to get the unique usernames.

Answer (score 1):

this `grep` with look-ahead could give what you want:

```
 grep -Po '^(\w+)(?=\s\d+\s\w+\sago$)' file
```